# Tidy way to replicate reshape2 aggregation with tidyverse functions

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2, tidyr, tidyverse

I understand that [by design](https://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/), `tidyr` does less than `reshape2`: `tidyr` never aggregates.

Is there a "right" way to replicate `reshape2`'s aggregation, in the sense of better following the tidyverse philosophy?

I usually combine a few dplyr verbs and then one from tidyr. I.e.:

To replicate

```
dcast(mtcars, gear~cyl, value.var = "disp", sum)

  gear     4     6      8
1    3 120.1 483.0 4291.4
2    4 821.0 655.2    0.0
3    5 215.4 145.0  652.0
```

One can do

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(gear, cyl) %>% 
    summarise(disp = sum(disp)) %>% 
    spread(cyl, disp)

Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: gear [3]

   gear   `4`   `6`    `8`
* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     3 120.1 483.0 4291.4
2     4 821.0 655.2     NA
3     5 215.4 145.0  652.0
```

I'll appreciate any insight on whether this is an optimal solution, and if it's not, what would be better and why

Comment: I'll hazard a guess  it's that it works better with the forward-pipe strategy of one step at a time

Comment: You could shorten it to `mtcars %>% count(cyl, gear, wt = disp) %>% spread(cyl, n)`, but that's pretty much it. There's not really a question here.

Comment: Many ways to skin a cat. It's not objective better whether you do it with `reshape2`, `tidyverse` or even in base.

Comment: Agreed that there are many ways to skin our cat (or our data), but when tidyr lost its aggregation function, what was supposed to replace it within-tidyverse?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35225052/spread-vs-dcast

Comment: @HAVB I think the way you've done it is fine. I think the "tidyverse way" is to work with the data in long form most of the time, using dplyr's aggregation tools, and then spread at the end for presentation. But this is probably too broad to get good answers.